# insert to a current table and update to another table php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables named interview and personal_info. I'm having a problem inserting values into my database. I need to insert the values of txtTest, txtIntervieweddBy, txtRemarksDate, txtComment and txtRemarks to interview table. There's also this txtRemarksStatus in the same form but its use is to update a row in a different table named personal_info.

```
<?php
    include_once 'php/connection.php';
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "trackingsystemdb");
    $number = count($_POST["txtIntervieweddBy"]);

    if($number > 0)
    {
        for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)
        {
            if(trim($_POST["txtIntervieweddBy"][$i] != ''))
            {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO interview (applicant_code, interviewed, dateInterviewed, comment, remarks) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["txtTest"][$i])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["txtIntervieweddBy"][$i])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["txtRemarksDate"][$i])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["txtComment"][$i])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["txtRemarks"][$i])."')";

            }
        }
    }

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $txtRemarksStatus=$_GET['txtRemarksStatus'];
    $sql = "UPDATE personal_info SET status =  '$txtRemarksStatus'          
            WHERE applicant_code = '$id'";

    if (mysqli_multi_query($connect, $sql)) {
    } else {
        echo "Error ".mysqli_error($connect);
    }

    header('Location: addinterview.php?insert=sucess');
    exit();

?>
```

Comment: The most obvious issue I can see is that you never execute your INSERT statement. You overwrite the value $sql (with the UPDATE query) before you ever run the INSERT.

Comment: Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: As well as this, **never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even do this is a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Answer (score 0):

Use it Like this:-

```
 include_once 'php/connection.php';
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "trackingsystemdb");
    $number = count($_POST["txtIntervieweddBy"]);

    if($number > 0)
    {
        for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)
        {
            if(trim($_POST["txtIntervieweddBy"][$i] != ''))
            {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO interview (applicant_code, interviewed, dateInterviewed, comment, remarks) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["txtTest"][$i])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["txtIntervieweddBy"][$i])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["txtRemarksDate"][$i])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["txtComment"][$i])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["txtRemarks"][$i])."')";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
            }
        }
    }

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $txtRemarksStatus=$_GET['txtRemarksStatus'];
    $sql = "UPDATE personal_info SET status =  '$txtRemarksStatus'          
            WHERE applicant_code = '$id'";

    if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
    } else {
        echo "Error ".mysqli_error($connect);
    }

    header('Location: addinterview.php?insert=sucess');
    exit();
```

Comment: this looks correct, although an explanation of what has changed - and more importantly why - would make it into a much better quality answer.

Comment: @bamboozled "did not work" doesn't give us much of a clue to help you with. Was there an error, or did your update's Where clause simply not match any rows?

Comment: print_r($sql); for update query then use it in phpmyadmin then see any errors are occured